# AWS upload a file to a specific user using s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Hi StackOverFlow community,

I have no code to show for this question and I am missing alot of knowledge around AWS so i don't even know what to search or look for.

Here is what i want to achieve

Use Case:

- User Signs up
- Goes to his/her account.
- Uploads a new profile picture.

Traditional Web Server

You would upload the file with the id of the user. (from previous request or session)

That way you can generate a name for the file, store it somewhere and reference that in the Database. How ever you decide. At the end the newly uploaded image, src path is in the Db and linked to the user.

I am trying to achieve the same thing on AWS.

These are the things that i think i understand.

S3 is used to store binary/static content
AWs Cognito is used to authenticate users and *(I'm am not very confident here)* is the equivalent of sessions.
Lambda is a web services that only accepts JSON.

How am I suppose to use those tools to achieve the desired effect.

I don't have code to try and if someone can point me in the direction of an example i would happily attempt and then return here if i have any futher questions.
I am just not sure if i have the right idea, am i on the right track. I keep searching but i can't find an example that could fulfill that use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to upload your files to s3 ,which backend type you want to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a *web application* (just like with traditional web servers). Your web application can then use AWS services.

**User Signs Up**

The users would connect to *your web application* and perform whatever sign-up process you wish to implement. The authentication and user store could be done with Amazon Cognito, or your own application logic and a database.

**Goes to their account**

Again, this is a user navigating around *your web application*.

**Uploads a profile picture**

They would be uploading to *your web application*. Your application can then store this picture in an Amazon S3 bucket. It is also possible to code a web page to [upload directly to Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html), but your web application would have to create the dynamic code behind the page to make this possible.

**General comments**

All of the above tasks are exactly the same as with non-AWS solutions. However, you can take advantage of various AWS services to assist, such as Cognito and S3.

You could go one step further and write totally serverless applications by using AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway, but that's a more difficult step to take.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with any authentication mechanism available like Cognito or your own and after authentication you can create S3 SignedUrls and directly upload files to s3 bucket(s).

This is a secured way of uploading files to s3.

S3 Buckets do have option to use prefix before the actual filename which you can use to seperate and maintain your files with respect to your users.

For e.g

```
2017/06/8/<user_id>/ is a kind of prefix information will give you the time.
```

Considering your backend system might include Java , here are steps to [Generate a SignedUrls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html) to upload files to s3.